# Segmentation fault when testing shellcode

Tags: segmentation-fault, shellcode

I am trying to execute a shellcode, however I am facing a problem to execute it.
(I am using a x86 32bit CPU)

```
char shellcode[] =
                                      // <_start>
          "\x31\xc9"                  // xor    %ecx,%ecx
          "\xf7\xe1"                  // mul    %ecx
          "\x51"                      // push   %ecx
          "\x68\x2f\x2f\x73\x68"      // push   $0x68732f2f
          "\x68\x2f\x62\x69\x6e"      // push   $0x6e69622f
          "\x89\xe3"                  // mov    %esp,%ebx
          "\xb0\x0b"                  // mov    $0xb,%al
          "\xcd\x80"                  // int    $0x80
```

The above code are from [here](http://www.shell-storm.org/shellcode/files/shellcode-517.php)

when I debug this with my gdb debugger, assembly code with address is shown like below

```
0xbffff6e6: xor    %ecx,%ecx
0xbffff6e8: mul    %ecx
0xbffff6ea: push   %ecx
0xbffff6eb: push   $0x68732f2f
0xbffff6f0: push   $0x6e69622f
0xbffff6f5: mov    %esp,%ebx
0xbffff6f7: mov    $0xb,%al
0xbffff6f9: int    $0x80
0xbffff6fb: add    %al,(%eax)
0xbffff6fd: jmp    0xbffff727
```

The problem is...
when I break at 0xbffff6e6, I can not execute the next instruction, mul %ecx
when I continue, gdb debugger gives me this error

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0xbffff6e6 in ?? ()
```

As far as I know segmentation error occurs when I tried to access the memory address that is not allowed to access.

How can I make it runnable on my PC? Again, I am using intel x86-32 CPU with Ubuntu Linux.
I appreciate in advance.

Comment: That's because data section is not executable, it has only READ and WRITE permissions.

Comment: thank you for your answer:-) it should be!! so how can i make my shell code runnable? as i googled, it says i can use mprotect function to grant executable permission. is it right? or is there any other way to do it??

Comment: See `ld` command optional section attributes to make your data segment executable. However, it is not possible to modify the program image in the memory to achieve this. It is only possible to modify the ELF section and run the program again.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is memory permissions.  Old shellcodes and tutorials on writing them do not consider security protections that have been introduced over the years.

What you're encountering is what happens when the NX (no execute) bit is set for the memory region where your shellcode resides.  The first instruction will run, but subsequent instructions will generate a segfault.

There are two ways you can run that code.  One is to compile it with the protections disabled.  Something like this worked for me:

```
bash $ gcc -m32 -g -fno-stack-protector -z execstack -o orig code.c -w
bash $ ./orig
$ uname
Linux
$
```

If you want to run the shellcode with modern protections turned on, you need to ensure that it runs from a memory region that has permission to execute.  So, if you make your program something like this, it should work:

```
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <errno.h>

char shellcode[] =
                                      // <_start>
          "\x31\xc9"                  // xor    %ecx,%ecx
          "\xf7\xe1"                  // mul    %ecx
          "\x51"                      // push   %ecx
          "\x68\x2f\x2f\x73\x68"      // push   $0x68732f2f
          "\x68\x2f\x62\x69\x6e"      // push   $0x6e69622f
          "\x89\xe3"                  // mov    %esp,%ebx
          "\xb0\x0b"                  // mov    $0xb,%al
          "\xcd\x80"                  // int    $0x80
  ;

void main() {
  char *buf;
  int prot = PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC;
  int flags = MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS;

  buf = mmap(0, sizeof(shellcode), prot, flags, -1, 0);
  memcpy(buf, shellcode, sizeof(shellcode));

  ((void (*)(void))buf)();
}
```

For more information on the NX bit, check out the [relevant wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_space_protection).